# Codeigniter Ajax. How to display Image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to display the picture in bootstrap modal using ajax. Only the image is not displaying, in the database is only the filename. For some reason I can't use php to display the image

image location:D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\uploads

I'm using these 2 codes to trial and error

View:

```
  <div id="banner3" name="banner3">
  </div>
  <img id="banner2" name="banner2">
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#manageMemberTable').on('click', '.get', function(){  
       var event_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       var event_title = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.event_title').html();
       $.ajax({  
            url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>Events/eventdetails/"+event_id,
            type:"POST",  
            dataType:"json", 
             success:function(data)  
            {  
                
                $('#event_title').text(data.event_title);
                $('#event_desc').text(data.event_desc);
                $('#when').text(data.start_date);   
                $('#Venue').text(data.venue);  
                $('#course').text(data.course); 
                $('#level').text(data.year_level); 
                $('#ids').val(data.event_id); 
        
                $('#banner3').append("<img src='uploads'"+data.color)
                 $('#banner2').attr("src",'uploads',data.color); 
                 $('#userModal').modal('show');
                
               
            } 
           
      
        })  

    });
});
```

Comment: what is path where your images are located ? Also `'uploads',data.color` should be `'uploads'+data.color`.

Comment: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\uploads

Comment: then try `"uploads/"+data.color` and see

Comment: I'd rather use absolute uris to avoid problems: `"/uploads/"+data.color` (assuming your `DocumentRoot` is `CapstoneFiles`).

Comment: how to put base_url in ajax??.. this is mine but error  $('#banner2').attr(<?php base_url() ?>"src","uploads/"+data.color);